# Magento 2: How to show Customer Attribute in Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I have created a custom customer attribute.

It is visible in customer registration page and customer dashboard

But it is not visible in **sales_order_grid**.

I want to display it how can I achieve it

Help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `sales_order_grid.xml` inside `adminhtml > ui_component` directory

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="business_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\BusinessName">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Attribute Title</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">25</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then create a class inside `Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\BusinessName.php`

```
<?php    
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;

class BusinessName extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $block
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
     */
    protected $assetRepository;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param Repository $assetRepository
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Repository $assetRepository,
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->assetRepository = $assetRepository;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($item["entity_id"]);
                $businessName = $customer->getBusinessName();
                if($businessName != ''){
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = $businessName;
                }
        }
    }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Hope it will solve your issue!

Let me know if have any query.